# Call staic block on front end

Tags: magento-1.9, cms

How to call static block in front end of site? 
Exact steps to display it by taking example of identifier: 'footer-link'

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can call it like this.

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="footer-link"}}
```

**in cms -> homepage-> content**

Comment: and if i want to add it on product

Answer (score 0):

You can reference static blocks within xml for pages like product pages:

```
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product.staticblock" as="staticblock" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Footer Links</argument>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-link</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Various blocks can be referenced depending on where you want your block to display.

Above XML should go in your theme within:

```
'Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml'
```

Or when within a module:

```
'view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml'
```

The below can reference a static block within phtml file within template:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('footer-links')->toHtml();
```

As suggested by Nikunj Vadariya to include static block from CMS use:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="footer-link"}}
```